# Evaluation of (a)synchronous design of ledger interface

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, architecture, inversion-of-control

I'm currently designing a ledger API, that should work with different implementations (e.g. based on Blockchain, traditional databases, or files).

Its purpose is to add/get messages to/from a concrete ledger. The messages get encapsulated in transactions, which have additional meta data like time, and author, etc. Initialization takes place in a `LedgerProvider`, which is not included.

There are also other parties that write to the ledger (e.g. in case of a blockchain-based implementation).

---

**Question**
Should the ledger interface be designed synchronous or asynchronous? And why?
At what data should one look when making this decision?

---

A synchronous ledger would need to be polled by its users, callbacks seem more convenient. On the other hand, classes like `InputStream` are also synchronous and some callback mechanism could be built on top (libraray polls internally and calls registered callbacks).

---

Below the synchronous version.

```
/**
 *
 * @param <M> Message type
 */
public interface Ledger<M> {    
    Transaction<M> addTransaction(M message);
    List<Transaction<M>> getTransactions();
    List<Transaction<M>> getTransactions(LocalTime since, LocalTime to);
}
```

That's what the asynchronous version would look like.

```
public interface Ledger<M> {    
    Transaction<M> addTransaction(M message);    
    void registerObserver(Observer o);    
    void unregisterObserver(Observer o);    
}

public interface Observer<M> {
    void update(Transaction<M>  tx);
}
```

Comment: "A synchronous ledger would need to be polled by its users, callbacks seem more convenient."  I think you are taking 'asynchronous' to mean 'event-driven' which isn't the case.  Synchronous simply means that a transaction request and it's confirmation are atomic.  It's completely valid (but perhaps uncommon) to have a asynchronous system that requires polling.  It seems to me that both of these designs are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you use the terms *synchronous* and *asynchronous* as defined by UML:

> A Behavior may be invoked synchronously or asynchronously. Synchronous
> invocation means that an invoking Behavior retains a reference to the
> invoked Behavior execution and waits for the execution to complete.
> Asynchronous invocation, on the other hand, means that the invoked
> Behavior execution proceeds concurrently with the invoking Behavior.

But first some remarks:

- `AddTransaction()` has a synchronous design in both interfaces because of its return value.  So the interface would not be purely asynchronous.
- Any method with a synchronous design can be invoked asynchronously (in java, [using `CompletableFuture`](http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/) ).

So the main difference between you two design is not synchronicity, but the way they allow you to access data.  So I strongly suggest that you use the more precise [*push* vs. *pull*](https://simplicable.com/new/pull-vs-push-technology) terminology instead.

---

#### The pull interface ("synchronous"):

The consumer has to query the ledger when data is needed data.

Advantage:

- The consumer can get a full up-to-date picture of the ledger, or a subset of it limited to a time interval.

Inconvenience:

- It's difficult and inefficient to get only new transactions.
- There is no way to ensure that new ledger transactions are **processed exactly once** if you are not also the originator.

So if you have to react to new transactions, you'd have to frequently query for the latest time interval, and filter out the transactions that you have already seen.  This is very resource inefficient (CPU, network, ...)

And if you need to do something exactly-once the filtering would be unreliable. Because, how can you reliably filter the already received data:

- based on the time stamp ?  but is the timestamp reliable enough ?
- based on a flag ? but is this possible with a blockchain-write-once ledger ?
- based on a list of already processed transactions ? But how to make it persistent when the process is shut down ?

Conclusion:

- if you need some exactly-once processing of new transactions, you cannot rely on this interface.
- if you have to monitor new transactions, this interface might cause inefficiencies.

#### The push interface ("asynchronous")

The consumers are informed by the ledger when something new is happening.  So it's event drivent.

Advantage:

- Monitoring new transactions is very efficient. There's no resources spent to wait for data, or filter out unnecessary data.

Inconvenience:

- It's not possible to get a set or subset of the transactions in the ledger, unless you'd create a copy of each transaction.
- It's difficult and unreliable to make analysis on past figures, because you'd have to update the indicators (min, max, sum, average,..) in real time, and data registered in the ledger while the process is down would not be received.

Conclusion:

- If you want to monitor reactively your ledger, this is the ideal interface
- If you want to process historical transaction data, this is almost impossible with this interface.

#### Conclusion

You have here two interface which are tailored to address very different needs.  So there's no universal best choice: it'll depend on your use cases.

As the two interfaces are not mutually exclusive, why not combine them to benefit from their respective strength ?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I'm not interested in old transactions so I will stick to the push approach.